# @input elements not displaying in form of variables

Tags: angular

in My Angular chat Application i am creating a new message component every time a message is received.
using the following code.

feedComponent.html

```
<app-message *ngFor="let message of chatMessages" [ChatMessage]="message"></app-message>
```

now here is my messageComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageModel } from '../model/messageModel';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-message',
  templateUrl: './message.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./message.component.css']
})
export class MessageComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() ChatMessage:MessageModel;
 userName:string="blind";
 messageContent:string="blind";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(ChatMessage = this.ChatMessage) {
    this.userName = ChatMessage.senderUsername;
    this.messageContent=ChatMessage.message;
    console.log("this is the received chat message =>"+ChatMessage);
    console.log(this.userName+" : "+this.messageContent);
  }


}
```

messageComponent.html

```
<div class="message-container">
    <p>{{ userName }} : {{ messageContent }}</p>
</div>
```

here is my message Model

```
export class MessageModel{
    public message:string;
    public senderUsername:string;

    public getMessage(){
        return this.message;
    }

    public setMessageContent(message:string){
        this.message=message;
    }

    public getSenderUsername(){
        return this.senderUsername;
    }

    public setSenderUsername(senderUsername:string){
        this.senderUsername=senderUsername;
    }

}
```

Now the problem is :
when i try to display whole chatMessage object it gets printed (in console as well as html)
but when i try to display it in form of variables(userName and messageContent) it doesn't show anything in html but **undefined**

here is my console output:

```
this is the received chat message =>{"message":"hello","senderUsername":"shubhamishu"}
message.component.ts:20 undefined : undefined
```

please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: You seem to recieve all the desired info inside ChatMessage. Have you tried simply using {{ChatMessage.message}} instead of messageContent in your view?

Comment: Why are you adding argument to ngOnInit?

Comment: `<p>{{ ChatMessage.userName }} : {{ ChatMessage.messageContent }}</p>` will work

Comment: @JacopoSciampi it doesn't work it shows  " : "  in Html view

Comment: Mh, can you please do a `console.log(this.ChatMessage)` in the constructor in `messageComponent.component,ts` ?

Answer (score 0):

the ngOnInit only executed when the component becomes visible (if you has not a *ngIf only one time), so you're equaling userName and messageContent only one time., You can use directity. Futhermore, ngOnInit has NOT arguments

```
console.log(this.ChatMessage.senderUsername,this.ChatMessage.message)

//Or in .html
<div>{{ChatMessage.senderUsername}}:{{ChatMessage.message}}</div>;
```

//or 
The other way is use a getter

```
get userName()
{
    return this.ChanMessage.senderUserName
}
get message()
{
    return this.ChanMessage.message
}

Or use a setter in the @Input
@Input() 
set ChatMessage(value)
{
    this.userName=value.senderUserName
    this.message=value.message
}
```

NOTE: Usually it's used CamelCase begin lowerCase to variables, so `chanMessage` better than `ChanMessage` and CamelCase begin upperCase to Class

Comment: i tried this `export class MessageComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() chatMessage:MessageModel;
 userName:string;
 messageContent:string;

  constructor() { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.chatMessage.senderUsername,this.chatMessage.message);
  }

 
}`

Comment: but it still shows "undefined undefined" and sorry for the above message.stack overflow comments can't be formatted.